# Example of a monomorphism and epimorphism that is not isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm starting with a course of Introduction to Category Theory, and perhaps is dumb what I'm asking but I'm looking for an example of a monomorphism and epimorphism that is not isomorphism. Can you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't call them exact duplicates